# Converting Playback Time to a Formatted String Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, string-conversion

I have a timestamp pulled from a video that I want to convert into a user-friendly string in javascript.

```
let now = Player.getCurrentTime();

let minutes = Math.floor(now / 60.0);
let seconds = ((now / 60.0) - minutes) * 60;

console.log(minutes+":"+(seconds < 10 ? "0":"")+seconds);
```

The console.log statement using the conditional operator works really nicely for quick results. Are there any basic Javascript functions that will allow me to create a string using the input as the console.log above?

---

**UPDATE:**

Quick shoutout to [MrPickles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1130193/mrpickles)
for the prompt response. I ended up just doing it manually via a helper function. If anyone needs a quick timestamp formatting, here's a quick freebie:

```
function formatTime(timestamp) {

    let minutes = Math.floor(timestamp / 60.0);
    let seconds;
    let rawSeconds = ((now / 60.0) - minutes) * 60;

    if(rawSeconds < 10.0) {
        if(rawSeconds < 1.0) {
            seconds = rawSeconds.toPrecision(2);
        } else {
            seconds = rawSeconds.toPrecision(3);
        }
    } else {
        seconds = rawSeconds.toPrecision(4);
    }

    let mString = minutes.toString();
    let sString = seconds.toString();
    let displayTime = mString+":"+(seconds < 10 ? "0":"")+sString;
    return displayTime;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, no.

There are date/time modules you can get to help with this but most of the popular ones are big. If this is all you are doing with the date then I would keep what you have.

If you find you are doing a lot with dates and formatting then [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/) may be an options.